# Draft.js apply code-block to pasted JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

While using draft.js, I have a check on the pasted text in the editor. I want it to apply a code-block if it is a JSON message. I currently have the following setup:

```
handlePastedText = (text, html, editorState) => {
 const newContent = ContentState.createFromText(text);
 const blockMap = newContent.getBlockMap();
 const newContentState = Modifier.replaceWithFragment(
   editorState.getCurrentContent(),
   editorState.getSelection(),
   blockMap
 );
 try {
   JSON.parse(text)
 } catch (error) {
   this.setState({
     editorState: EditorState.push(
       editorState,
       newContentState,
       'insert-fragment'
     )
   });
  return 'handled';
 }
 this.setState({
   editorState: EditorState.push(
     editorState,
     newContentState,
     'insert-fragment'
   )
 }); 
 this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleBlockType(editorState, 'code-block'));
 return 'handled';
```

};

However when I run this, it just makes the editor a code block but doesnt insert any of the text.